# What is indentation good for?

Tags: paragraphs, grid-typesetting

I am a German native speaker and I have a question that concerns latex, i.e. the command `\noindent`.

As I would do it, a text with several paragraphs would look like this:

> Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in  [...] nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
>
> Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud [...] qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

The start of a new paragraph is obvious by a space ob about 0.5 to 1.5 lines between them.

Now in the Latex standard setting, we get is like this:

> Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in  [...] nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. _________________________________________________________________
> ______Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud [...] qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

But his looks just stupid in some cases:

> Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in  [...] nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna idet ud. _______________________________________________________________________________
> ______Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam:
>
> ***** Some Figure or chart *****

So can anyone explain what indentation is good for?

Comment: It is a visual cue to help reading comprehension.

Comment: Without indentation, how would you tell if the space following an equation, figure, table, or set-off quotation begins a new paragraph?

Comment: Go to your book shelf and check. You will find that quite a lot books uses identation. Its advantage over spaces is that it can't disappear at page breaks. Regarding your "stupid case": a lonely line can look odd too. I would simply move the text into the previous paragraph. Or even better let the figure float and use \ref to reference it.

Comment: Why the large space before the indentation? If you really have that, something odd is going on. But it is impossible to say what since you've given us no clue to your code.

Comment: Indentation is the norm in traditional typography. Just take a look at any litterature book. Adding white spacing to separate paragraphs is bad for what is called in French (not sure of the exact wording in English) the ‘gris typographic’ (typographic grey?) — the overall uniform grey look  of a page.

Comment: It leaves space for your local monks to draw in a fancy initial letter or paragraph marker.

Comment: Isn't this a typography question rather than TeX/LaTeX?

Comment: Note this is basically a duplicate of this question where the accepted answer points out that indentation is not the usual style in German http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101644/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the answer there is wrong in that aspect: most German books (at least most of my German books) *do* have indentation.

Comment: Yes, a popular German guide to typography recommands indentation: http://www.ph-weingarten.de/schreibwerkstatt/downloads/typokurz.pdf. It is definetly worth to read.

Comment: @clemens whether the answer there is right or wrong my comment saying it says what it says is correct, so I'm in the clear:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :)